# Firestore: How to get the object data from firestore in IOS (Swift) and display it in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure in firestore database like  object form. I need to retrieve the data from firestore and display it in tablebview in swift

```
-

collection//users
        -authid
       - collection//Split
         - auth id
         - collection//SentInvitations
           -automatic id
             -Invitee(i)(object)
                .name:bnnn
                .phonenumber:567788
                .amount:123
            - Invitee(2)
                .name:aaaa
                .phonenumber:987654321
                .amount:198
```

where i = no.of invitees
Now I need to retrieve these all invitees and display into table view

***Code I tried to retrieve the data from firestore***

```
func loadData(){
    let authid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
   let docRef =  db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(authid!).collection("Split").document(authid!).collection("SentInvitations").document(senderautoid!)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                        if let city = document.flatMap({
                            $0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
                                return Invite(dictionary: data)
                            })
                        }) {
                            print("City: \(city)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }
                    }

    }
```

***and my model class Invite***

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol DocumentSerializable2
{
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}
struct Invite {
    var PhoneNumber:Int
    var Amount:Int
    //var Status:String
    var dictionary:[String:Any]{
        return [
            "PhoneNumber":PhoneNumber,
            "Amount":Amount,
            ]
    }
}
    extension  Invite : DocumentSerializable2{
    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]){
        guard let amount = dictionary["Amount"] as? Int,
            let phonenumber = dictionary["PhoneNumber"] as? Int else { return nil}
        self.init(PhoneNumber:phonenumber, Amount:amount)

        }
    }
```

when I execute this code it does to the else condition document does not exist but in firestore it contains the document. To get these there is any  other method to solve [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe provide a screenshots of your firestore database console so that we can see the structure from there. Providing the structure isn't going to help us pinpoint the mistake you might have made while fetching

Comment: @Serj I have added the screen shot of my data structure

Comment: After applying flatmap, are your Invite dictionary objects initialized with the keys and values in your Firestore? I don't see a city variable.

Comment: @ericl I initialised at document.flatmap line : if let city = document.flatMap({
                            $0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
                                return Invite(dictionary: data)

Comment: Your struct 'Invite' is initialized with 'amount' and 'phonenumber' only. If you put a breakpoint and inspect at 'city', what is that value?

Answer (score 0):

Alright after discussing the problem with Vijju we missed one point that is Firestore doesn't use `Swift` types in its dictionary but `Objective-C` types. Thus something that is expected as an `Int` should be first casted to `NSNumber` and then from that `NSNumber` you get its `Int` value. So summarizing with code:

```
init?(dictionary: [String:Any]){
        guard let nsNumberAmount = dictionary["Amount"] as? NSNumber,
            let nsNumberPhoneNumber = dictionary["PhoneNumber"] as? NSNumber else { return nil}
        let phoneNumber = nsNumberPhoneNumber.intValue
        let amount = nsNumberAmount.intValue

        self.init(PhoneNumber:phonenumber, Amount:amount)
    }
```

Comment: Yaa , I didn't find that . Thanks for that

Comment: You're welcome! @vijju if my answer was the correct answer and it helped don't forget to upvote and mark it as the correct answer for other readers

Comment: No actually it is auth id

Comment: I will update my answer showing with your screenshot why I doubt its authId

Comment: After Split is an auth id Iam sure of that

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot from the `Split` collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172280/discussion-between-vijju-and-serj).